# How can I change the background image with WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to change the background image of the Firefox's new tab (about:newtab) with a WebExtension. I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
   if(window.document.URL == "about:newtab"){
       window.document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss050e066094/iss050e066094~orig.jpg)"
   }
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "description": "An example extension",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "wallpaper",
  "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "theme",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "55.0a2"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Anatomy of a WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) page (perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: I've read the link you give me but I did't find the solution. Moreover, I read the docs of themes but I don't find the answer.

Comment: OK. I pointed you at that documentation because the code that you have shown for your *background.js* file implies that you are not aware of how WebExtensions are organized. Having a `load` listener and changing the style of the `body` in that script doesn't make sense, and is completely ineffective. While the background script is associated with a page, the page is never shown.

Comment: I haven't yet played with the `theme` interface ([manifest.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/theme), [JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/theme)), so I'm not sure if *exactly* what you have described is possible with WebExtensions (it's certainly not *convenient*). OTOH, one possibility is that you can define a *different* new tab page using [`chrome_url_overrides`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides), but that's not the same.

Comment: However, my reading of the `theme` interface is that it affects the header (or "chrome" portion) of the browser only.

Comment: Is this something that you are wanting for yourself only, or something that you desire to distribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you cannot alter about: pages due to security reasons.

If you really want another background image on about:newtab, you will need to override the new tab page with your own implementation using [chrome_url_overrides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides). Newtab overriding is available since Firefox 54 (implemented in <s>[Bug 1234150](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1234150)</s>).

You would do it like this:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
  "newtab": "my-new-tab.html"
}
```

So your manifest would become something like this

```
{
  "description": "An example extension",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "wallpaper",
  "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "theme",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "version": "1.0",
  "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "55.0a2"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "my-new-tab.html"
  }
}
```

Implementing your own custom new tab page is a non trivial task:

- You will need to implement top visited sites. You are able to do this using the [topSites api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/topSites).
- Probably you want to implement search as well. Since you can't read the searchengines yet ([Bug 1352598](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1352598)) you might want to implement search by hardcoding URLs in your addon, adding a dropdown to select your favorite search engine. Next, when the user entered a query and presses ENTER, you can replace the current "New tab" page with the search results page using the [tabs.update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update) method, replacing the url property with the url of the search page + query.

I've opened a bug report asking for an API to set the background image on about:newtab and about:home. See [Bug 1391912](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1391912).